# CLOB type in liquibase turns to VARCHAR in SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, liquibase, varchar, clob

I have the following entry in my liquibase xml:

```
<changeSet author="lars" id="1">
    <createTable tableName="STATUS">
        <column autoIncrement="true" name="AUTOID" type="BIGINT">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="PK_STATUS"/>
        </column>
        ...
        <column name="DATA" type="CLOB(1048576)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="VERSION" type="BIGINT">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
     </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

But when I use liquibase to run this on an MS SQL Server Standard Edition, v12, I see that the `DATA` column has been created as type `VARCHAR`.

I use liquibase maven plugin v3.2.0

The driver I use is `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`, `sqljdbc42.jar`, i.e. version 4.2.

Anyone has any idea why this happens?

Comment: `clob` doesn't take a size as far as I know. Did you try to simply use `type="clob"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [`ClobType.java`](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/datatype/core/ClobType.java) class.

In the method `toDatabaseDataType` it has an `else if` section for the MSSQLDatabase type:

```
else if (database instanceof MSSQLDatabase) {
    ...
```

I don't know anything about MS SQL but it seems to me that liquibase (among other things) checks the version number of the MS SQL db and returns a different type depending on the db version. Maybe this is better suited on a MS SQL db and for convenience liquibase translated it directly?

Comment: This is exactly what was happening. Liquibase was translating this into a maximum size nvarchar due to it being an MSSQL db. On a DB2 db it created a CLOB as the xml specified.